# How to apply DataTrigger for all specific-type elements on UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I have next UserControl:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="..." />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButton}" BasedOn="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SmallButtons}" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
      ...
      <local:MyButton ..Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}" />
      <local:MyButton ..Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}" />
      <local:MyButton ..Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}" />
      ...
      <local:MyButton ..Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The problem is that `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SmallButtons}" Value="True" >` is not working. What is wrong and how to make it work?

And I want trigger to be applied for all `MyButton`s on this grid.

DataContext is OK, there is OnPropertyChanged event when data applied, but I never get breakpoint on SmallButtons get method.

Comment: turn on  debug messages for databinding and see output window to find out what's happening

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly setting the Style of the Buttons to the style called "MyButtonStyle" so your implicit style that is based on "MyButtonStyle" won't get applied.

Try to remove the Style attribute of the Button elements:

```
<Grid>
    ...
    <local:MyButton />
    <local:MyButton />
    ...
</Grid>
```